# Unable to save decoded image from Base64 string

Tags: c#, image, base64

I am saving an Image decoded from a Base64 String the moethod sucessfully converts Base64 String to Image without any exception but while saving , it gives exception.

*Here is the code*

```
string serverpath = Server.MapPath("~/myImage");
imgFromString.Save(serverpath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

`Save()` *method gives this exception*

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
at RgInfo_Service.Service1.PutFile(String NameList, String EmailList, String PictureList, String DateList)in C:\Documents and Settings\awaqar\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RgInfo_Service\RgInfo_Service\Service1.asmx.cs:line 55
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. You have already posted this before. If you don't get an answer there, it means that there is something wrong with your question. Either there isn't much information to diagnose or you need to rephrase for better understanding.

Comment: i have deleted that question , i tired it in another way but i am facing same exception...

Comment: Generic GDI error occurs mostly when the image is not in the correct format. Try assigning it to some picture box to see if the image is successfully converted.

Comment: the code is basically in a webService. without any interface . .

Comment: well for testing purposes, you can create an interface. doesn't takes long.